# New version of a class has a new field; how do I handle unit testing the class?

Tags: c#

I have a unit test project build over an older version of a class. Let's say I'm working on a new version which adds a field to the class, like below.

```
public class Customer
{  
  public string FirstName { get;set; }
}


public class Customer2
{  
  public string FirstName { get;set; }
  public string LastName { get;set; }
}
```

In my unit test, do I just create a new Customer2 class with the new field in it and test against that class?

Comment: This is an appropriate case to use polymorphism.

Comment: Show what your _current_ unit test does - I'm guessing you want a _new_ unit test rather than updating the _existing_ test.

Comment: why aren't you adding LastName to customer?  seems a BIG mistake to create Customer2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit tests exist to test logic not classes. So you shouldn't create a unit test just because you add 1 property to a class. If you just added a new field to the class, your existent unit tests will be affected by that, and if something breaks you will see that affecting the result of the unit test. If because of the new field you needed to create new services/components/methods/etc... in this case you should create unit tests for those new things to prove that your logic is well implemented.

**Edit**

Case you create properties with logic inside getters and setters, then you should test that, otherwise there's no need to create tests for POCO objects